# OPENROWSET worked fine from SMB share but after moving the file to an FTP server, I started getting Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

We have used the following code to load an xml file from an smb share and everything worked fine till we moved the source file to an ftp server.

Here is the code that loaded the file without error before moving the file:

```
INSERT INTO [XXX].[edrf].[kxml](XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'G:\Data\Saved\current-ls.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

This is the same code with an FTP path:

```
INSERT INTO [XXX].[edrf].[kxml](XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK "\\Hk3780\RTS\Acc05\Dat02\RTT\current-ls.xml", SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Nothing was changed on the Database level. Both the sql service account and the user have full access to the file. But we keep getting the following error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\Hk3780\RTS\Acc05\Dat02\RTT\current-ls.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)

Could anyone please assist in resolving this issue.

Yes, the sql service account has access:
[image: SQL Service Account]

Comment: Does the service account that SQL Server is running have access to the share, `RTS` on the host `Hk3780`? The fact you are getting the error suggests not.

Comment: You need to give the SQL Server service account permissions on the share. I might point out that *both* of these are SMB shares not FTP, the first is a network mapped drive, the second is a bare network share name

Comment: Thanks Larnu, yes the service account has access.

Comment: I see that the service account you are using is a member of that group, but what _permissions_ does that group have to the target directory? Error Code 5 specifically means that the user doesn't have permissions.